# Google Maps V3 - directionService is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put a direction service onto my map, but cannot get it to work. Here is the html:

```
<div>
        <span class="bold">From:</span> <input id="start" type="text" size="60" maxlength="150" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="bold">To:</span> <input type="text" disabled="disabled" size="<?php echo $address_length;?>" value="<?php echo $address ;?>"/>
        <input id="end" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $latlng ;?>" /><br/><br/>
        <span class="bold">Mode of Travel:</span>
            <select id="mode">
              <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
              <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
              <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Find Directions!" onclick="calcRoute()";/>
    </div><br class="clear" />
    <div class="inline">
        <div id="mapDiv" style="width:950px; height:550px; border:1px solid #FD5F00;">
            <noscript><h3 style="color:red; margin:150px 0 0 250px">Oppps. Please activate JavaScript to view this map</h3></noscript>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And down the bottom of the page I have some inline Javascript

```
$(function() {
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlng; ?>);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
function calcRoute() {
    var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
}
```

You can see that the latlng is being populated from a PHP variable. Everything seems to be working correct, the initial map loads, etc.

In the JS function calcRoute if I alert out the varr values using

```
alert(request.toSource());
```

I'm geting all the correct data (origin, start, and end), but the very next line is the one that is failing, my JS error is "directionService is not defined".

Been looking for hours trying to fix this, but cannot find out what the problem is even though this is about as simple as a google map gets :-(

If anyone has any thoughts I'd be really greatful, this is driving me bonkers!

Comment: Don't worry guys, I'm an idiot! I moved the 3 vars inside the jquery on page load condition to outside and it works fine now... This question is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Comment from original poster:**

> I moved the 3 vars inside the jquery on page load condition to outside and it works fine now... This question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


function initialize() 
{
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() 
{
    var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

        if(selectedMode=="DRIVING")
        {
            var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
        }
        else if(selectedMode=="WALKING")
        {
            var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
            };
        }
        else if(selectedMode=="BICYCLING")
        {
            var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.BICYCLING
            };
        }

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
        <span class="bold">From:</span> <input id="start" type="text" size="60" maxlength="150" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="bold">To:</span> <input type="text" id="end" />
        <span class="bold">Mode of Travel:</span>
            <select id="mode">
              <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
              <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
              <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Find Directions!" onclick="calcRoute()"/>
    </div><br class="clear" />
    <div class="inline">
        <div id="mapDiv" style="width:950px; height:550px; border:1px solid #FD5F00;">
            <noscript><h3 style="color:red; margin:150px 0 0 250px">Oppps. Please activate JavaScript to view this map</h3></noscript>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>







use this code,it will work fine.
```

Comment: Could you please include an explanation to the code? What is different to the original question's code? What advantages does it have? It is not really helpful to anyone without it.